# Data structure similar to stack

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Which data structure can you advise to use in the following situation:

I use Java

I need smth like a stack - so last in first out, but a stack of fixed size, for example only 5 elements could be put inside, and when a new element is put onto the stack, the element at the bottom of the stack should be discarded, and I also want to get element by the index, that is the newest element has index 0 and the oldest element has index 4.

Is there smth appropriate in Java?

I've tried to use java.util.Stack, but for example if I set size to 3 and try to add 4 elements they all are added to the stack.

Comment: A ring buffer sounds perfect here, assuming you keep it fixed-sized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has [ArrayDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html), which is basically a growable ring buffer. If you want to keep it at a fixed size, just check the size before pushing, and pop the bottom value if the size is too big.

Comment: Thx for pointing in the right direction, basically stack is OK, I just check if max size is reached I remove an element at position 0 and push a new element.

Comment: Using an array deque is faster because removing the bottom element is O(1) instead of O(n) for a standard arraylist based stack.